# over salted an uncooked steak

Tags: salt, steak, mistakes

I seasoned uncooked rib steaks yesterday (using a truffle sea salt). cooked 1 today and it was way too salty. How can I salvage the 2 remaining steaks. I cooked the 1st steak in the oven broiler.Thanks

Comment: If you can still see a lot of crystals on your steak, you can rinse it off.

Or soak it in water for a few hours or overnight, then wrap it in paper towels and let it dry in the fridge throughout the day.

You can try what this related question’s answer suggests: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/46751/24248

Comment: A tip for future reference... Use flower salt to season the meat, and do it ontly moments from putting it on the heat!

Comment: An even better tip - put the salt on the table and let the diners choose how much to use, if any.

Answer (score 3):

You could try "reverse brining", using a low salt beef stock to eliminate or reduce the loss of flavour in the steaks.

(Stocks I make myself are very low salt so that I can reduce them as needed without them becoming too salty.)

Answer (score 2):

@wumpus has a great suggestion using reverse brining. Other than tasting excessively salty, your over-salting will have an effect on the texture of the meat and also suffer from dehydration. Hydration is mostly reversible with some penalty in lost flavours which may or may not be noticeable. Salt ions will change the structures of proteins and most of that will be irreversible. This will inevitably affect the texture and mouth-feel of the meat. Only you can tell if the one you had cooked was too tough. If so, do not expect soaking with water or reverse brining to undo that. If that is the case, the second piece may be ruined as steaks. Once you have dealt with the saltiness, you can repurpose it for other dishes. You can cut them into strips for something like stroganoff or slice them for a stir fry for example where toughness may be masked.

Comment: Or even grind them for perhaps [the best hamburger you'll ever try](https://www.thespruce.com/fifty-dollar-rib-eye-burger-recipe-335078).  But skip the salt!

Answer (score 1):

I would rinse it off, as suggested in the comments, but I would also try a trick with potatoes. Potatoes are a great salt neutralizer, so I would thinly slice a raw potato and line both sides of it... a layer underneath it, and a layer on top. Then broil or bake as usual. I have had success in de-salting over-salty chicken this way. You can also drop slices in an over-salted pot of soup, stew, or in a casserole.